# Deleted questions access for privileged users on iOS?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I had commented on a question yesterday from my SO iOS application on which the OP has also commented afterwards but he also decided to delete the question in the following hour.

So when I went to access the OP's comment, the application notified me that the question has been deleted. But I'm a privileged user and I can access deleted questions and answers on the site.

Is this feature possible to have on the iOS application ?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible now, since the Stack Exchange API, which is used by the app, doesn't allow access to deleted posts.

So they could create that possibility, but I don't think they will actually do it to prevent exposing too much information using the API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just up-voting the answer for now so the question doesn't get closed as resolved. I'd like to hear @BrianNickel opinion about it too.