# Show more specific "Page not found" error in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, ios-app, deleted-questions, mobile-app

Trying to view a deleted question in the SE mobile app will show a generic "Page not found" error, with the option to open in Safari.

> [image]

Opening the page in Safari will show a more specific error, "This question was voluntarily removed by its author". It also provides a list of possibly similar questions.

> [image]

I'd be nice if we could view this extra information without leaving the SE app.

Answer (score 5):

The lack of information is simply because [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) (which the apps use), doesn't return any information on deleted posts. [This duplicate request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238533/307988) from when the message was even more generic explains this and resulted in the message being changed to what it currently is.

See also these related requests on being able to see deleted posts through the app:

- [Deleted questions access for privileged users on iOS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285808/307988)
- [Viewing deleted posts in the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278703/307988)

Comment: I've decided to unaccept this answer, as I still believe having more detailed error messages would be a useful feature. However, this is still an excellent explanation as to why this feature isn't currently implemented.